# Get size of a file before downloading in Python

Tags: python, urllib

I'm downloading an entire directory from a web server. It works OK, but I can't figure how to get the file size before download to compare if it was updated on the server or not. Can this be done as if I was downloading the file from a FTP server?

```
import urllib
import re

url = "http://www.someurl.com"

# Download the page locally
f = urllib.urlopen(url)
html = f.read()
f.close()

f = open ("temp.htm", "w")
f.write (html)
f.close()

# List only the .TXT / .ZIP files
fnames = re.findall('^.*<a href="(\w+(?:\.txt|.zip)?)".*$', html, re.MULTILINE)

for fname in fnames:
    print fname, "..."

    f = urllib.urlopen(url + "/" + fname)

    #### Here I want to check the filesize to download or not #### 
    file = f.read()
    f.close()

    f = open (fname, "w")
    f.write (file)
    f.close()
```

---

@Jon: thank for your quick answer. It works, but the filesize on the web server is slightly less than the filesize of the downloaded file.

Examples:

```
Local Size  Server Size
 2.223.533  2.115.516
   664.603    662.121
```

It has anything to do with the CR/LF conversion?

Comment: Possibly. Can you run diff on it and see a difference? Also do you see the file size difference in the binary (.zip) files? Edit: This is where things like Etags comes in handy. The server will tell you when something changes, so you don't have to download the complete file to figure it out.

Comment: you're right, I wasn't using "wb" when opening the local file for writing.
Works like a charm! Thx

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I have reproduced what you are seeing:

```
import urllib, os
link = "http://python.org"
print "opening url:", link
site = urllib.urlopen(link)
meta = site.info()
print "Content-Length:", meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0]

f = open("out.txt", "r")
print "File on disk:",len(f.read())
f.close()


f = open("out.txt", "w")
f.write(site.read())
site.close()
f.close()

f = open("out.txt", "r")
print "File on disk after download:",len(f.read())
f.close()

print "os.stat().st_size returns:", os.stat("out.txt").st_size
```

Outputs this:

```
opening url: http://python.org
Content-Length: 16535
File on disk: 16535
File on disk after download: 16535
os.stat().st_size returns: 16861
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is os.stat().st_size not returning the correct size?

---

Edit:
OK, I figured out what the problem was:

```
import urllib, os
link = "http://python.org"
print "opening url:", link
site = urllib.urlopen(link)
meta = site.info()
print "Content-Length:", meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0]

f = open("out.txt", "rb")
print "File on disk:",len(f.read())
f.close()


f = open("out.txt", "wb")
f.write(site.read())
site.close()
f.close()

f = open("out.txt", "rb")
print "File on disk after download:",len(f.read())
f.close()

print "os.stat().st_size returns:", os.stat("out.txt").st_size
```

this outputs:

```
$ python test.py
opening url: http://python.org
Content-Length: 16535
File on disk: 16535
File on disk after download: 16535
os.stat().st_size returns: 16535
```

Make sure you are opening both files for binary read/write.

```
// open for binary write
open(filename, "wb")
// open for binary read
open(filename, "rb")
```

Comment: when you do `site = urllib.urlopen(link)` you have performed a file download , so it is not size before downloading its infact downloaded to buffer from where you are retrieving the content-length

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz I think it's when you attempt to read() that the file actually get downloaded in the buffer [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3009697/7213370)

Comment: `urllib.urlopen` is no longer valid in at latest 3.6

Answer (score 28):

Using the returned-urllib-object method `info()`, you can get various information on the retrieved document. Example of grabbing the current Google logo:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> d = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.co.uk/logos/olympics08_opening.gif")
>>> print d.info()

Content-Type: image/gif
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 Aug 2008 16:20:19 GMT  
Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2038 19:14:07 GMT 
Cache-Control: public 
Date: Fri, 08 Aug 2008 13:40:41 GMT 
Server: gws 
Content-Length: 20172 
Connection: Close
```

It's a dict, so to get the size of the file, you do `urllibobject.info()['Content-Length']`

```
print f.info()['Content-Length']
```

And to get the size of the local file (for comparison), you can use the os.stat() command:

```
os.stat("/the/local/file.zip").st_size
```

Comment: I have been using this solution, however I have hit an edge case where sometimes the content-length header is not defined. Can anyone explain why it wouldn't be consistently returned?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087370/determining-content-length-when-not-specified-in-http maybe explains it?

Answer (score 12):

A [requests](http://python-requests.org)-based solution using HEAD instead of GET (also prints HTTP headers):

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
# display size of a remote file without downloading

from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import requests

# number of bytes in a megabyte
MBFACTOR = float(1 << 20)

response = requests.head(sys.argv[1], allow_redirects=True)

print("\n".join([('{:<40}: {}'.format(k, v)) for k, v in response.headers.items()]))
size = response.headers.get('content-length', 0)
print('{:<40}: {:.2f} MB'.format('FILE SIZE', int(size) / MBFACTOR))
```

#### Usage

> ```
> $ python filesize-remote-url.py https://httpbin.org/image/jpeg
> ...
> Content-Length                          : 35588
> FILE SIZE (MB)                          : 0.03 MB
> ```

Comment: Not every response will include a `content-length` --sometimes the response is generated using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, in which case there's no way to know without downloading.

Answer (score 7):

The size of the file is sent as the Content-Length header. Here is how to get it with urllib:

```
>>> site = urllib.urlopen("http://python.org")
>>> meta = site.info()
>>> print meta.getheaders("Content-Length")
['16535']
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

Also if the server you are connecting to supports it, look at [Etags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) and the [If-Modified-Since](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers#Requests) and [If-None-Match](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers#Requests) headers.

Using these will take advantage of the webserver's caching rules and will return a [304 Not Modified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) status code if the content hasn't changed.

Answer (score 6):

In Python3:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> site = urllib.request.urlopen("http://python.org")
>>> print("FileSize: ", site.length)
```

Comment: This downloads the file!

Answer (score 3):

For a python3 (tested on 3.5) approach I'd recommend:

```
with urlopen(file_url) as in_file, open(local_file_address, 'wb') as out_file:
    print(in_file.getheader('Content-Length'))
    out_file.write(response.read())
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using Python 3 and looking for a quick solution using the `requests` package:

```py
import requests 
response = requests.head( 
    "https://website.com/yourfile.mp4",  # Example file 
    allow_redirects=True
)
print(response.headers['Content-Length'])
```

Note: Not all responses will have a `Content-Length` so your application will want to check to see if it exists.

```py
if 'Content-Length' in response.headers:
    ... # Do your stuff here
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much more safer way for Python 3:

```py
import urllib.request
site = urllib.request.urlopen("http://python.org")
meta = site.info()
meta.get('Content-Length')
```

Returns:

```
'49829'
```

`meta.get('Content-Length')` will return the "Content-Length" header if exists. Otherwise it will be blank

Comment: Otherwise it will be `None`. Still +1 for your answer. Note: If you want it to return e.g. `0` if there's no Content-Length - do `meta.get('Content-Length', 0)`. Overall, my one-liner is `urllib.request.urlopen(url).info().get('Content-Length', 0)`

Answer (score 0):

@PabloG Regarding the local/server filesize difference

Following is high-level illustrative explanation of why it may occur:

The size on disk sometimes is different from the actual size of the data.
It depends on the underlying file-system and how it operates on data.
As you may have seen in Windows when formatting a flash drive you are asked to provide 'block/cluster size' and it varies  [512b - 8kb].
When a file is written on the disk, it is stored in a 'sort-of linked list' of disk blocks.
When a certain block is used to store part of a file, no other file contents will be stored in the same blok, so even if the chunk is no occupuing the entire block space, the block is rendered unusable by other files.

Example:
When the filesystem is divided on 512b blocks, and we need to store 600b file, two blocks will be occupied. The first block will be fully utilized, while the second block will have only 88b utilized and the remaining (512-88)b will be unusable resulting in 'file-size-on-disk' being 1024b.
This is why Windows has different notations for 'file size' and 'size on disk'.

NOTE:
There are different pros & cons that come with smaller/bigger FS block, so do a better research before playing with your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and reliable one-liner for Python3 using urllib:

```
import urllib

url = 'https://<your url here>'

size = urllib.request.urlopen(url).info().get('Content-Length', 0)
```

`.get(<dict key>, 0)` gets the key from dict and if the key is absent returns 0 (or whatever the 2nd argument is)

Answer (score 0):

you can use requests to pull this data

```
File_Name=requests.head(LINK).headers["X-File-Name"]

#And other useful info** like the size of the file from this dict (headers)
#like 

File_size=requests.head(LINK).headers["Content-Length"]
```