# How to get image file size in python when fetching from URL (before deciding to save)

Tags: python

```
import urllib.request,io
url = 'http://www.image.com/image.jpg'

path = io.BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
```

I'd like to check the file size of the URL image in the filestream `path` before saving, how can i do this?

Also, I **don't** want to rely on Content-Length headers,  I'd like to fetch it into a filestream, check the size and then save

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909/get-size-of-a-file-before-downloading-in-python

Comment: Why the need to not rely on Content-Length headers? You can check the size of a `BytesIO` object the same way you can with any open file object, using seeking to the end and `fobj.tell()`. But if you use the Content-Length headers you can *prevent having to read the whole image into memory first*.

Answer (score 2):

Try importing `urllib.request`

```
import urllib.request, io
url = 'http://www.elsecarrailway.co.uk/images/Events/TeddyBear-3.jpg'
path = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
meta = path.info()

>>>meta.get(name="Content-Length")
'269898' # ie  269kb
```

Comment: But now your answer is functionally no different from llogiq and goes directly against what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the size of the `io.BytesIO()` object the same way you can get it for any file object: by seeking to the end and asking for the file position:

```
path = io.BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
path.seek(0, 2)  # 0 bytes from the end
size = path.tell()
```

However, you could just as easily have just taken the `len()` of the bytestring you just read, before inserting it into an in-memory file object:

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
size = len(data)
path = io.BytesIO(data)
```

Note that this means your image has *already been loaded into memory*. You cannot use this to prevent loading too large an image object. For that using the `Content-Length` header is the only option.

If the server uses a chunked transfer encoding to facilitate streaming (so no content length has been set up front), you can use a loop limit how much data is read.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the server for the content-length information. Using `urllib2` (which I hope is available in your python):

```
req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
meta = req,info()
length_text = meta.getparam("Content-Length")
try:
      length = int(length_text)
except:
      # length unknown, you may need to read
      length = -1
```