# how to get file size without downloading it in python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

surely you have used a download manager. they detect and show the length of the file without downloading it

I know i can do this:

```py
import requests
resp = requests.get("https://Whereever.user.wants.com/THEFILE.zip")
print(f"your file has {resp.headers['content-length'] \ 1048576}.")
...
```

but `get` downloads the content (THEFILE). so i can tell use the length after download.
how to do that before download in python?

Thanks for detailed-answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get size of a file before downloading in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909/get-size-of-a-file-before-downloading-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `GET` request, do `HEAD` request:

```py
resp = requests.request('HEAD', "https://Whereever.user.wants.com/THEFILE.zip")
```

The HTTP `HEAD` method requests the headers that would be returned if the `HEAD` request's URL was instead requested with the HTTP `GET` method. In your case, where URL  produces a large download, a `HEAD` request would read its `Content-Length` header to get the filesize without actually downloading the file.

Comment: I have seen that some servers don't support HEAD (some sayd this to me) am i write ??

Comment: Perhaps some do not, but that would simply be stupid in general, as it would kill client-side caching which header based usually and that means higher traffic/load for the server. You can assume any non crappy server knows and supports HEAD.

Comment: cool . a great answer to my question in my comment. thanks bro